# Glassfish 3.1.2 Cluster Remote Monitoring JConsole/VisualVM

Tags: glassfish, monitoring, glassfish-3, visualvm, jconsole

I have a cluster with two nodes, and I am trying to connect to those nodes with VisualVM or JConsole so I can check the health of the JVM. However, I cannot connect to the nodes, with JConsole it just says "Connection Failed" and with VisualVM it just continuously pops up the prompt for username and password. So it seems like it is not authenticating properly. I am using the admin username and password. What is strange is I can connect to the DAS JVM just fine remotely, it is just a problem with the nodes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research it appears that glassfish 3.1.2 (b23) has a bug in it that prevents JMX connections to remote instances (basically nodes in a cluster). At this point in time there is not a work around, and they are not sure if they are going to backport the fix to 3.1.2 Keep an eye on it. http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18450

Answer (score 0):

Are you using port 8686? url should be  ip:8686 ? and if you enable the authentication of AS, you have to provide username/password on jconsole connection screen.

Comment: The nodes (JMX_SYSTEM_CONNECTOR_PORT) are setup with port 28686. The authentication realm is set to admin-realm which is the realm that stores the admin username/password, and that is what I am trying to connect with. Connecting to the nodes used to work fine in glassfish 2.1.1 it is just a problem in 3.1.2 it seems.

Comment: I am using Glassfish 3.1 and JMX_SYSTEM_CONNECTOR_PORT is set 28686, However I can connect Glasssfish JMX interface at port 8686 via not only  jconsole but also my own application.

Comment: Your cluster node must be on the same box as your DAS, the DAS is hosted on 8686 by default, so you are not connecting to that node, just the DAS